# Can't get Serving Static Files using node js (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have learning Node JS and try to open the Serving Static Files using the below function on node js express. But I got the Cannot GET error check the screenshot

I have a proper folder structure.

I refer to the below article
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

[image]

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**Here is the full code**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log(host, port)
})
```

**Folder structure**

```
node_modules
server.js
public/
public/images
public/images/Minions_characters.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.use(express.static('public'));
> ```

You didn't specify a path as the first argument to `use`.

You've mounted the contents of the `public` directory at `/`

Therefore the correct URL does not start with `/public`

---

Either:

- remove `/public` from the URL
- add `/public` to the mount point: `app.use('/public/, express.static('public'));`